# Spring retry for DAO call with XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I have a method which invokes a DAO call something like this

```
@Overide
public List methodGetList (Parameter) {
 List myList = listDao.getList()
}
```

I want to retry if the dao layer throws SQL Exception. Where should the @Retryable annotation should be used, on the method in the interface, or on the class giving the implementation or on the getList() method in the DAO.

And I am using following XML configuration to enable retry in  the application

```
 <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.annotation.RetryConfiguration" />
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 1.2 or later (current is 1.2.4), it can go on either the interface or the implementation [thanks to this fix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/commit/51523c0b4008a0b13697b6731cb0fd7f662498b5).

`@Recover` currently only works on the interface [PR here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/pull/124).